# Eav model , Foreach Loops

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, architecture, entity-attribute-value

I'm creating a car-seller website. I have a `car_properties` table to store my car properties, such as ABS, Climate, Navigation, Alarm, etc.

I'm using EAV model for car properties table, so my table looks like:

```
id , name , value
```

and keeps data like:

```
name : ABS ,     value : 1 
name : climate , value : 1
```

On `show-single-car` view, I'm displaying them. The problem is I'm using lots of `foreach` loops. On the same `show-single-car` view page, I have multiple areas to show these properties. Some of them are at the right side of the page, some of them at the bottom.

Is it true to use it this way, or can I fetch them without `foreach`? I don't feel good when using a lot of `foreach` loops.

my method :

```
public function showcar($id)
{
    $car = CarSale::findOrFail($id);
    return view('frontend.product')->with('car' , $car);
}
```

my view :

```
 @foreach( $car->carproperty as $property)                  
    {{ $property->name }} - {{ $property->value }}                                 
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Can we see  your show-single-car view markup and the controller code that renders it?

Comment: hello ,  i added them to question

Comment: I think since you are not looping over the database access part of this, then the loops you have are absolutely fine and should present no issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ - vote-to-close a question because it is off-topic here, not because you think it may be on-topic somewhere else. In addition,in this case specifically, the question is not particularly off-topic on Stack Overflow, and worse, the short, example code is not on-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @rolfl: noted. I do now recall seeing a post on meta about the off-topic-here/on-topic-there flagging guidelines -- my bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not looping over the database access part of this, the loops you have are nothing but constructs used to render your UI, which IMO are perfectly safe and should present no issues performance- or maintenance-wise.

The model(s) being rendered exists very briefly in memory in order for their data to be accessed and rendered by the framework.